# relationship between battery voltage and discharge rate

Tags: battery-chemistry

I guess my question roots from me not understanding what a load represents to the battery.

Is a 4V battery able to discharge at a higher rate (C rate) than a 2V battery?

Or does it completely depend on the load which will always extract current at the same rate regardless of the battery voltage.

In my current understanding I feel as if a higher voltage battery will allow for faster discharge rates if needed (higher C rates of discharge).

It's difficult for me to test this with a potentiostat because in my understanding it can always force negative currents on discharge (GCPL mode lets say) which can be higher than the maximum discharge rate a battery can deliver to a load.

Could someone please clarify this for me. I am very confused.

Comment: A trivial answer is: For two batteries that are identical except for voltage, supplying an identical, real, load, the higher-voltage battery will discharge faster.

Comment: thank you. so to follow up on this, to the battery, is the load just a resistor? what makes load X demand more current than load Y and how is this different than a potentiostat discharge (GCPL or chronopotentiometry mode)?

Comment: @medivh that's only true sometimes. What if the load is a current sink? What if it's a negative resistance?

Comment: @Phil Frost: I specified a real load so it's definitely not a current sink. I guess there's technically nothing in math that prevents you from treating a power SOURCE as a negative load but I feel pretty confident when I promise you: That's not what guywithaquestion is considering.

Comment: @medivh a current sink is a real load, if by "real" you mean "something that can exist in reality" or "an impedance with a zero complex part". It isn't an *ohmic* load, but many practical loads aren't.

Comment: The latter one - I meant no complex part. There are current sinks with no time components?

Answer (score 2):

> is a 4V battery able to discharge at a higher rate (C rate) than a 2V battery?

*Maybe*. Voltage represents the extent to which electric charge wants to flow from the "+" side of the battery to the "-" side. So, a battery with a higher voltage exerts more force on the electric charge, which *might* result in the charge moving faster, depending on how whatever is connected between the battery terminals responds to more force. Many circuits will permit charge to flow faster if the voltage is increased, but some will hold the rate of charge (current) constant, while some may even respond to a higher voltage by permitting *less* current.

But, how fast the charge actually flows depends on what's attached to the battery, to what extent it impedes the flow of charge, as well as the [internal resistance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_resistance) of the battery.

Furthermore, if we are talking about the "C rate", we are talking about rate of discharge relative to the capacity of the battery to store electrical energy. So, a low capacity battery will have a higher rate of discharge relative to a higher capacity battery, all else being equal, because the discharging is a larger fraction of its capacity.

If your goal is to discharge a battery as quickly as possible, then you would want to do all of these things:

- connect the terminals with a low impedance, like a really short, fat wire.
- use a battery chemistry with a low internal resistance
- use a high voltage battery
- use a low capacity battery

Comment: so to clarify my question. if the load is huge (a fridge). which battery will discharge faster if connected to the fridge circuit, given they contain the same energy and same internal resistance, a 4V battery or a 2V battery.

Comment: @guywithaquestion a load is characterized by more than how big it is. If your load is actually a fridge, probably it's specified to run at a particular voltage. Increasing or decreasing the voltage outside of this range will probably damage the fridge.

Comment: its a hypothetical question. in this scenario, i am interested in how the batteries will discharge and i can afford to swap refrigerators more frequently than i swap socks.

Comment: @guywithaquestion I've already given you the general answer. If you want a specific answer about fridges, you will have to say specifically which fridges.

Comment: @guywithaquestion: Just as a word of caution: Do NOT short circuit a battery for fun, like it was suggested in the answer. I added a related warning to the answer.

Comment: i dont need an answer about fridges. please pretend i didn't mention fridges. i am trying to understand how batteries work, not a tutorial on how to operate refrigerators.

Comment: @guywithaquestion how the battery discharge rate changes with a change in voltage depends on the *load*, not the *battery*. You are asking something like, *if I increase the pressure in a hose, will more water flow?* Well, it depends. Is there someone on the other end of the hose that pinches it off whenever the voltage rises? If so, the answer is no. Is it flowing into a turbine, working against drag? If so, the answer is yes. *It depends on the load*.

Comment: aha! my question is exactly that. "if I increase the pressure in a hose, will more water flow?" so i guess the answer is yes. so basically there is no way to extract as high rates from a 2V battery as there is possible to extract from a 4V battery, given same resistances and loads.

Comment: ok i should correct my previous question. there is no way for the 2V battery to spontaneously provide the same discharge rate as the 4V battery given the same capacity, resistances and loads.

Comment: @guywithaquestion if the load is purely resistive, then the current at a given voltage is given by Ohm's law. The discharge rate as a "C rate" will also depend on the battery capacity. But, real batteries with higher voltages usually have higher internal resistance than lower voltage batteries of the same chemistry, which might reduce the maximum safe or possible discharge rate. I'm afraid there just isn't a simpler answer.

Comment: let me take a more specific example. a DC electric motor moving a car. will it experience the same torque with current provided from a 4V battery with a capacity of 1000 Ah as with current provided from a 400V battery with a capacity of 100 Ah? according to math, P=V x A it should be the same, but would 4V be enough to move that car, even though it is supposedly moving so much more current (same C rates)? i have read about "energy efficiency" where higher voltage batteries are more efficient deliverers of energy as opposed to higher capacity ones, but don't understand why.

Comment: @guywithaquestion if you want to know specifically about motors, that sounds like a [new question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).